I have been doing Fortran 95, but whenever I run a program, it gives me the error message: "Undefined Reference to WinMain"
Recently I downloaded gfortran through tdm-gcc, and I downloaded Visual Studio Code with three add-ons: C/C++, Modern Fortran, and Code Runner. I created a folder labeled "Fortran Projects" and attached it to VSC. Whenever I run any program, no matter what it is, I always get the same error message:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function main': C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v8-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
I am new to programming, so can anyone tell me what's wrong?
By the way, this is on Windows 11
One program I tried was a simple Hello World program, and it gave me the same error message. Same with more advanced programs.

I'm not a Fortran expert. But I run Fortran command-line applications in Visual Studio Community.

Great! But which workload would I choose to use Fortran

As far as I remember, I installed this: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/oneapi-standalone-components.html

And this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=intel-corporation.fortranonline

Well I was trying to find the solution to the problem while using the same editor. I had seen a tutorial and had done the exact same thing, so there does not seem to be a problem with the editor.

You might want to check on the linker settings.  If there's a complaint about a missing WinMain, conventionally that would mean that something in the toolchain is expecting this to be a windowed app rather than a console app.

How do I check the linker settings?

Nevermind I found out I just had to save my file before I ran the code.
